# Bitwise operator of booleans

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

i've a small problem with the bitwise "&" comperator of PHP.
Im trying to compare both boolean values but when I compare them the bitwise comperator gives me an integer in stead of a boolean.

Both variabeles are checked if they are valid. If they are, then the function return, of course, a true.

```php
$bValue1 = true;
$bValue2 = true;
```

When I combine this in a var_dump with a bitwise operator then it returns int(0). Why?

```php
var_dump($bValue1 & $bValue2);
```

Comment: Why would you use a bitwise operator on a boolean?!?

Comment: Because that's what a bitwise operation does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

& is bitwise AND. Assuming you do 14 & 7:

```
14 = 1110
 7 = 0111
---------
14 & 7 = 0110 = 6
```

&& is logical AND. Consider this truth table:

```
$bValue1 = true;
$bValue2 = true;

$bValue1     $bValue2     $bValue1 && $bValue2
false        false         false
false        true          false
true         false         false
true         true          true
```

&  => do the bitwise AND operation. it just doing operation based on
      the bit values.

&& => do logical AND operation. It is just the check the values is 
       true or false. Based on the boolean value , it will evaluation the expression

Answer (score 2):

The '&' operator is operating on the bits so it's interpreting the booleans as integers and then comparing the bits.

You should use the logical operator '&&' to compare Booleans.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question **why** is as follows:

Your variables both are true. On bitwise comparison, true turns to integer(1) (false turns to 0) and **return an integer containing all matching/equal bits instead of a boolean**.

```
true => 1

1 & 1 === 1
```

Result in words: The bits on both sides are equal (1).

```
101 & 110 === 100
```

In words: First bit is not equal (right to left), second isn't, position 3 has equal bits.

From PHP.net:

```
$a & $b     And     Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set.
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

The result on comparing bits is **integer**, and **neither a bitmask nor its comparison mask are boolean**. They are (unsigned)integers of variable byte length by nature.

To clearify:

> When I combine this in a var_dump with a bitwise operator then it
>   returns int(0). Why?

Is plain wrong, it returns `int(1)`.

Comment: `1 & 1 = 1`. `&` doesn't return a "position", it returns a new byte in which all bits which are set in *both* operands are set, and all other bits are not. All bits in `1` and `1` are the same, hence the result is `1`. `2 & 3` would result in `2`.

Comment: Sorry bro, then I guess I've never implemented a bitfield before and the PHP interpreter is also wrong: http://3v4l.org/kYjUO And how would you explain that ``'a' & 'b' = '`'``?

Comment: Ok you are right concerning the result is 1 instead of 0 (I just copied the OPs dumb output instead of testing myself), but it is not a boolean, it is still the position of the equally bits

Comment: Mmmmm, better, but "returns a position" still doesn't make much sense. It simply returns a new integer whose value is the *AND* combination of each of the two operands' bit pairs. Hmm, was that sentence actually simpler now?

Comment: You are correct, sorry broo. Why does the OP say his output is int(0) anyways?

Comment: Meh, why's he using bitwise operators when he doesn't know what they do to begin with? ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's because "bitwise" refers to the numerical value of the bytes.

You want a LOGICAL operator:

```
var_dump($bValue1 && $bValue2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should use logical operators on booleans (&&, ||, ==). Bitwise operate on integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use AND  at the place of & you can use && also

```
$bValue1 = true;
$bValue2 = true;
var_dump($bValue1 & $bValue2);
```